# Cypress - empty select element list when executing in viewport

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, cypress

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
it('try select', () => {
cy.visit('http://automationteststore.com/index.php?rt=account/create')
cy.get('select:visible').eq(1).select(5, { force: true })
})
```

When executing in Cypress the select list looks like that:

```
<select name="zone_id" id="AccountFrm_zone_id" class="form-control " data-placeholder="">
</select>
```

When opening in normal mode in browser the list looks like that:

```
<select name="zone_id" id="AccountFrm_zone_id" class="form-control " data-placeholder="">
<option value="FALSE"> --- Please Select --- </option>
<option value="3513">Aberdeen</option>
<option value="3514">Aberdeenshire</option>
<option value="3515">Anglesey</option>
<option value="3516">Angus</option>
<option value="3517">Argyll and Bute</option>
<option value="3518">Bedfordshire</option>
(...)
</select>
```

Thus when running a Cypress test I face an error:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.select() failed because it could not find a single <option> with value, index, or text matching: 5
```

Looks like the page is not loading the options when loaded inside Cypress viewport. Anyone

1. Select by value
2. Select by text
3. Select by index
4. Made sure the element is visible

Comment: That <select> for *Region / State:* appears as empty when i opened that page.

Answer (score 3):

The list of options for the select are fetched by API, but if you look at the Network tab in devtools and filter by the country code `222`, you will see the fetch failed with a CORS error.

This is simply because you used `http://` protocol when you should be using `https://` protocol.

This is the working test

```js
cy.visit('https://automationteststore.com/index.php?rt=account/create')

cy.get('select[name="country_id"]')  
  .select('United Kingdom')

cy.get('select[name="zone_id"]')    // access by name not position
  .select('Argyll and Bute')        // select by text not position
  .should('have.value', '3517')     // verify
```

Comment: So why the second select works properly and I can select the position in Cypress?

And thank you dearly for your support!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, but the problem is due to an error in the URL of  `cy.visit()`. If you change it, you get a passing test.